# What does SMA Tee Adapter do?

Tags: rf, connector

SMA tee connector is something like this:
[image: SMA tee connector]

What does it do? Is it something like a power divider?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It just provides straight connections. If you know anything about RF then you should realize that it will only work **properly** for low frequencies. At high frequencies the characteristic impedance is affected resulting in reflections and unwanted attenuation of your signal.

I would only use these to split or combine a signal up to 100 MHz or so and even that is pushing it.

Comment: Exactly, that's why I asked. The connector did not make any sense to me.

Comment: Besides that, real RF engineers would only use the gold plated ones ;-)

Comment: and "proper" power splitters look like this: https://www.google.nl/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjM8J7LtrPKAhVGfw8KHUDsASkQjRwIBw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.telcoantennas.com.au%2Fsite%2F2-way-signal-splitter-sma-female-connectors&psig=AFQjCNEPC3CftFhRVQxGpEkpeqe9-gDkYQ&ust=1453208738550316

Comment: To be honest, the similar BNC T-adapter is used often as an emergency solution in broadcast where you might need a signal split close to two monitors or similar. Frequencies there are often 750MHz to 1.5GHz (3Gbps "3G-SDI") for regular HD signals.

Comment: @Araho Then obviously those (digital) 3G-SDI signal and/or the standard is very robust against signal distortions due to reflections etc. The signal is still harmed/changed/distorted but it is indeed possible that enough can be recovered so it is still usable for transferring the video stream. It might for example switch to a lower datarate so that it can still get something through. I can see how that would be useful in a professional/broadcast setup (you just want it to work) so they might have designed the standard like that.

Comment: No, it's not changing data rates, those are very specific. I agree that it is very robust, and of course you won't use a T-adapter when using a cable that is the maximum length (usually 100m, -20dB attenuation over RG-59 / RG-6 75Ohm coax). Those receivers are true black magic when it comes to recovering signals!

Comment: @Araho You contradict yourself, how can a standard not change datarates when multiple (specific of coures, using unspecific rates is asking for trouble in any standard) rates are supported ? It might not do that when the signal degrades but that's something different. It's not black magic when it is designed to do this recovering. It just means extra margins are in place and these are used up when the signal is bad.

Comment: Let me rephrase myself then - it does not do any negotiation of datarates to improve signal integrity, as you hinted to in your comment. Of course, it does some serious recovery, and of course it's designed this way with proper margins, but it's still very impressive (Look at ie. http://m.eet.com/media/1056975/nationalsemi-3.jpg).

Answer (score 4):

One good use of coaxial tee adapter is attachment of coaxial cable tuning stub or surge protection.

Answer (score 1):

> What does it do?

There are three ports all connected together - ground is common and the middle pins are all common.

> Is it something like a power divider?

No, it's a three port junction suitable for coaxial cable connections. Power division is dependent on source and load impedances.

Answer (score 0):

It's used to create a ["bias Tee"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_tee#Application), which allows DC power to be delivered to the output port of an up-stream device, such as an amplifier or photodetector, while the RF signal retains proper impedance matching from source to load.  That prevents creation of inter-symbol interference in a digital system, or standing waves on an analog transmission system.

The [bias Tee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_tee#/media/File:Bias_t.png) has, on one port, an SMA low-pass filter with its other end connected to a power supply.  A second port of the Tee has an in-line blocking capacitor attached, the other end of which has a cable that delivers the signal downstream.  A cable attached to the third, unblocked port, delivers power upstream.